Mantras and stotras to reduce graha doshas and badhas
What are some stotras and mantras which can act as a remedy for graha dosha and badhas?
I know shiva Sahasranama and Vishnu Sahasranama but they are too long for my Upasana time . I want something shorter and effective.

Recite Navagraha stotras like this --- https://stotranidhi.com/en/navagraha-stotram-in-english/

Does it placate bad mars in one’s chart? @Rickross
